# ArcGis and GeoCortex

Tags: c#, .net, geolocation, geocoding, arcgis

we are tying to set-up [GeoCortex](http://www.geocortex.com/)  with our ArcGis server but can't seem to get it right.

We do see some of the requests that have been made to the application, but we don't have a lot of details about it, only the number of image requested,

I was wondering if you guys had any problem with this (if you ever tried it) and if I could get a checklist of things to look for.

Thanks

p.s.: I know that this is a very precise subject, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: We're about to get GeoCortex and the GIS people have been learning more about it.  There should be a gisoverflow site just for that field, if there isn't one already.  I wonder if work would sponsor the monthly fee for stackexchange...

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm only an intern over here and I doubt the people at my job would pay for a stackexchange even if I think it's a really good idea.

Comment: There is a GIS Stack Exchange, it's http://gis.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Seems like our GeoCortex version was outdated and there was bug in it.